# How to display gmap according to the textbox1 and textbox2 in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I want to display the gmap ..

if i enter City name in textbox1 and another city name in textbox2

then the gmap will display and the both cities will be highlighted in the gmap with its distances ...

i wanna do this using vb.net, asp.net

Comment: I would suggest trying something then post a question upon encountering difficulties.  Not ask us to write the code for ya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out: [Reimers GoogleMap control](http://www.reimers.dk/) It is an amazing control and is easy to use.

Comment: Excellent example of how a good answer can save a bad question.